# firebase/firestore is not working but firebase/firestore/lite is

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have using Firebase Firestore database for my react-native app.

With firebase 9.0.1 update, I only able to read and write data using firebase/firestore/lite but I cannot connect with firebase through the regular firebase/firestore. Is anyone encountering this issue or can offer a solution?

"firebase": "^9.0.1",
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.65.1",

```js
// firebase > config.js

import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";

import { getAuth, signInAnonymously, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore/lite';


const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "", 
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: "",
};


// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
export const auth = getAuth(app)



// index.js
This work and can reach my firestore
import { getFirestore, doc, deleteDoc } from 'firebase/firestore/lite';

Does not work, can’t reach my firestore
import { getFirestore, doc, deleteDoc } from 'firebase/firestore/';

/////////

async function deleteDocument() {
      await deleteDoc(doc(db, "cities", "222"));
  }
  
deleteDocument()
```

Error message that I'm getting:
[image]

Comment: Can you share some code how you use it. How you initalize your app and how you import the modules.

Comment: @TarikHuber I am able to delete the doc '222' in the "cities" collection with firestore if I use: import { deleteDoc, } from 'firebase/firestore/lite';  but if I use  import { deleteDoc, } from 'firebase/firestore it wouldn't work.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it in a `try-catch` and see if there are any errors ?

Comment: For version 9.0.x , you need to use new commands for importing , you can find them here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69096276/module-not-found-cant-resolve-firebase-in-users

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix 'firebase/firestore/lite' and 'firebase/firestore' in you code. Please choose one and use it everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

> Delete data from Cloud Firestore

To delete documents, fields, and collections:

Example: to delete "222" you want

```js
const db = getFirestore(app);
const docRef = doc(db, 'cities/222');
docRef.delete();
```

if use firebase version > 8.x.x

```js
import { getFirestore, doc, deleteDoc } from 'firebase/firestore/lite';
// OR
import { getFirestore, doc, deleteDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';

const store = getFirestore(app);
const docRef = doc(store, 'cities/222');

await deleteDoc(docRef);
```

Comment: OP is using modular SDK. That syntax in your answer is older namespaced syntax.

Comment: @Dharmaraj Oh, i see... i will update answer

Comment: @hongdeveloper, with firebase 9.0.0, they don' use delete() anymore. It has changed to deleteDoc().

Comment: Reason for downvote: This answer doesn't address the original question. We still don't know why is only `lite` version working. Instead we have an example of how to delete a document.